# Why SwiftUI use associatedtype for the body?

Tags: flutter, swiftui

```swift
public protocol View {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    associatedtype Body : View

    /// Declares the content and behavior of this view.
    var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

the SwiftUI use associatedtype to its body, what's the point, does it have any advantage?

why doesn't it make the returned type of `body` as a view like flutter does??

```swift
public protocol View {
    var body: View { get }
}
```

Comment: To have possibility control types explicitly, and make bodies of all standard views opaque, using, eg, `extension Image : View { public typealias Body = Never }`. Boom... and it is not possible to reuse/wrap standard Text, Image, etc. bodies.